# How to get all the non-Zero values from a Dataframe[SparseVector] in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a DataFrame[SparseVector] obtained from HashingTF from ml library in Spark. Below is my schema:

```
root
 |-- docId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- docNGrams: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- HashedNGrams: vector (nullable = true)
```

HashedNGrams is a sparse Vector of 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647 number of features(The maximum). An example of HashedNGrams is:

```
[doc/00000.txt,(2147483647,[70921,235056,....],[1.0,2.0,...])
[doc/00001.txt,(2147483647,[6067499,8758008,....],[1.0,1.0,...])
......
......
```

What I want is to get Just the Values:

```
70921,235056
6067499,8758008
.....  , ...
```

from this DataFrame to a Vector,List[Int], whatever, so to do some manipulation of the data. What I have tried so far is:
1)Try to convert it to a dense Vector but it gives me an out of limits VM exception
2)Tried every possible solution i found from here but with no lack at all! They all give me an error.
3)Even save it in a file and then tried to take these values as a String(haven't completed this yet, but i feel it's Very wrong approach).

Please help!

Comment: In your case `70921,235056` are indices not values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user defined function (UDF) that transforms a `SparseVector` into an array of values - here's how to add a new column named `values` with these arrays:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val valuesOnly = udf { s: SparseVector => s.values }
val result = df.withColumn("values", valuesOnly(col("HashedNGrams")))
```

**UPDATE**: as noted by @zero323, the OP is indeed after the *indices* and not the values. As commented, this can easily be achieved by using `s.indices` instead of `s.values` in the UDF.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! By the combination of the two answers(yours and @zero323 ) i derived what i wanted. I was looking that for Ages!!!!  `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val valuesOnly = udf { s: SparseVector => s.indices }
val result = df.withColumn("values", valuesOnly(col("HashedNGrams")))`

Comment: Glad it helped - indeed I didn't notice the expected values in the example were actually the indices. Would be helpful if you upvote/accept the answer to let other users know this question is answered.

Comment: I did! But it gives me: Votes cast by those less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicity displayed post score.